# Jasper hide staticText and textField don't remove the space

Tags: jasper-reports

I created a main report and subreport with Jasper. From main report I am sending 2 parameters (Value A and Value B) to the sub report which either one can be 0. if one parameter gets 0 it needs to get hide.
[image]

I am using `<printWhenExpression>` and `isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"` attributes to hide these elements. They are hiding properly according to the parameters, but if Value A get 0 there will be space in between KKK and Value B.

[image]

for Value B I have set the `positionType="FixRelativeToTop"`. It can be seen in the property box but not in the source of the JRXML. 
Is there any way to get rid of this white space ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got this sorted by making single Value B row as another sub report. Remove all print when conditions from the sub report.
Added `printWhenExpression` and  `isRemoveLineWhenBlank` attributes on the main report , sub report `reportElement` tag.

Answer (score 0):

three position types are using in the jasper report for placed the element in the report. in the jasper report documentation,

- positionType="Float" - The element floats in its parent section if it is pushed downward by other elements found above it. It tries to conserve the distance between it and the neighboring elements placed immediately above it
- positionType="FixRelativeToTop" - The current report element simply ignores what happens to the other section elements and tries to conserve the y offset measured from the top of its parent report section. This is the default position.
- positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" - If the height of the parent report section is affected by elements that stretch, the current element tries to conserve the original distance between its bottom margin and the bottom of the section.

try with following simple modification. for Value B, set "Position Type" property to "Float".

```
<reportElement positionType="Float" ... />
```

`positionType` property is the attribute of `reportElement` tag as given below,

```
<textField>
    <reportElement positionType="Float" ... />
    <textElement>
        <font ... />
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression> ... </textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```